# Extract PID from sk_buff.

Tags: linux, networking, kernel

I am looking some way to determine to what process sk_buff is directed. I know that there is no straightforward way to do that. To obtain `sk_buff` I'm using `netif_rx notifier`. I've had to use notifiers instead of NETFILTER, because NETFILTER works in interrupt context (but, if NETFILTER can be in any way more usefull in this case, I can switch).
What I've tried so far: 
To get `struct pid *sk_peer_pid` from `struct sock *`. 
Compare `struct file *` with opened file descriptors `struct files_struct` of each task. This is too heavy.
Network namespaces. This was useless, since all processes use the same namespace, and this feature is not enabled by default on the device. 

My last idea is to compare somehow destination port from the packet, with ports that processes are listening. Is there any way to do that? To get desired port number from packet, and then look it up, and see what process is listening on it?

Comment: Why do you want to do that (and why do you want to do that inside the kernel, and not e.g. use iptables)?

Comment: Besides that, this module has to also monitor other events like issued IOCTL's to the device, when device is registered, unregistered, etc.